# ADFS disaster recovery plan

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs

What are the best practices for ADFS disaster recovery plan with specifications as below:

2 Different ADFS FarmsFarm

1 :- ADFS 2012 farm with SQLFarm
2 :- ADFS 2012 farm with WID database.

Answer (score 0):

To setup ADFS Disaster Recovery Site

There are 2 options to do this, which will give some idea on your scenario.

Scenario: ADFS Farm (ADFS Servers, Proxy) setup on Azure, which need similar setup on another region to prepare for Disaster recovery.

Plan A :    Create a ADFS server and WAP server in the DR site and join to the existing Farm.

1. Create 2 Azure VMs in the DR site
2. Make sure the 2 VMs are able to communicate over port 443
3. Make sure the server for ADFS is joined to the same domain and has a line of site to your domain controllers (TCP ports 80 & 443)
4. Make sure the server of ADFS is able to communicate with your existing primary ADFS server over TCP ports 80 & 443
5. Install the ADFS server role and configure it to join the existing ADFS farm
6. Install the WAP server role and complete the configuration wizard to build up the WAP trust with ADFS
7. In the DR failover drill, modify the internal/external DNS record to point to the DR site ADFS/WAP server and test if the authentication service is working.
8. You can shutdown the servers on DR site afterwards, please make sure to boot up the machines when there are configuration changes on your production servers to sync up

Plan B : Use ADFS Rapid Restore Script to back up existing ADFS server and quickly restore later

1. Install the MSI on your existing primary ADFS server
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-rapid-restore-tool
2. Backup the current ADFS service to a protected file system or even Azure Storage Container using PowerShell commands like below
   Backup-ADFS -StorageType "FileSystem" -StoragePath "C:\Users\administrator\testExport" -EncryptionPassword "password" -BackupComment "Clean Install of ADFS (FS)" -BackupDKM
3. The backup file will be named to the pattern "adfsBackup_ID_Date-Time"
4. You can schedule a task to run this back up from time to time so there will always be an up to date back up
5. In case anything happens, create a new Windows Server with the same OS version, join it to the same domain and leverage the same PowerShell module to restore from back up
6. This tool can only back up ADFS service, you need to add another server, install the WAP role and re-configure the trust following the wizard.

Reference To Create and customize recovery plans : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-create-recovery-plans